# Division function alternate for mathematical calculation

Tags: javascript

In java script

```
var res = eval('5/7 + 8/7');
```

The above function shows the result as `1.8571`...

But i want the output as `13/7`

How do i get this using `eval()` function.

Comment: Check this out: http://hypervolu.me/~erik/fraction.js/

Comment: `eval()` is evil. You most likely don't need to use it.